# Return List in Asp Mvc 5 With Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

i need to Return List Wtih Angular2 in Asp Mvc 5 .

i Write this code in Asp Mvc :

**Model => Recipes.cs:**

```
public class Recipes
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult RecipesList()
    {
        var Recipe = new List<Recipes>
        {
            new Recipes
            {
                name="Kianoush",
                description="Enginner",
                imagePath="app/assets/Image/Hydrangeas.jpg"
            },
            new Recipes
            {
                name="El",
                description="Enginner",
                imagePath="app/assets/Image/Desert.jpg"
            }
        };
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Recipe, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            }),
            ContentType = "application/json",
            ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
    }
```

**Angular :**

**Recipes:**

```
export interface IRecipes {
name: string;
description: string;
imagePath: string;
}
```

**app.Reipe:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { } from './RecipeList/app.RecipesList';

@Component({
    selector: 'recipes-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/Recipes/app.recipes.html'
})

export class RecipesComponent {

}
```

**app.Recipe.html :**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <RecipesList-app></RecipesList-app>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">

</div>
```

**RecipeService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IRecipes } from '../Recipes';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private _ProductUrl = '/home/RecipesList';
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IRecipes[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._ProductUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IRecipes[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("All : " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError)
    };
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**RecipeList:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IRecipes } from '../Recipes';
import { ProductService } from '../RecipeList/RecipeService';

@Component({

    selector: 'RecipesList-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/Recipes/ReipesList/app.RecipesList.html'
})
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {

    Recipes: IRecipes[];
    constructor(private _productservice: ProductService) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productservice.getProducts();
    }
}
```

**app.RecipeList.html:**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
<div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{Recipes.name}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{Recipes.description}}</p>
</div>
<span class="pull-right">
    <img class="img-responsive"
         src="{{Recipes.imagePath}}"
         style="max-height: 50px;" />
</span>
```

But it not Show me any things . whats the problem ? how can i show list ?

/*************************************************************************************************/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How data is assigned to `Recipes` variable in `RecipesListComponent`? You are missing `subscribe()` call.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productservice.getProducts().subscribe((res: IRecipes[]) => {
      this.Recipes = res;
  },
    error => console.log('Something went wrong!')
  );
}
```

[refer angular 2 http documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

In case you get any error, please post here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `*ngFor` in you `app.recipe.html` page .

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of Recipes">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <img class="img-responsive"
                 src="{{recipe.imagePath}}"
                 style="max-height: 50px;" />
        </span>
    </a>
```

Comment: Have you put a debugger to check whether you getting data in Response from HTTP Operation

Comment: how can i check that ? i using visual studio 2015

Comment: put a debugger using f9 and check step by step by pressing f10

Comment: typescript debugging is same as Javascript jsut write `debugger` in before the code you want to check/debug